# PHP date format issue while converting to big int

Tags: php, date, bigint

I want to store two dates as of type big int to database I have an array which is serialized and sent array values to second form and array consists of

```
[checkin] => 01-07-2015
[checkout] => 03-07-2015
```

After converting this using

```
$arr['checkin'] = strtotime($arr['checkin']);
$arr['checkout'] = strtotime($arr['checkout']);
```

I'm getting value as `1435689000 1435861800` respectively, which are one day less than actual date values.

and just to inform in my server if my code is

```
<?php echo date('d-m-y', '1435689000');?>
```

then the output will be `01-07-15`, and if I tried to use `gmdate` function as follows

```
echo gmdate('d-m-y', '1435689000');
```

The output will be `30-06-15`

I am not able to figure out what is the issue is will you please help. Thank you..

Comment: Probably your database timezone and PHP timezone being different...

Comment: @Amadan any idea how can i check whether both timezones are different or same??

Comment: @Amadan i think i am not able to get proper value of date conversation. later i can think about timezone for database and PHP.

Comment: My alien-mind-probe-protecting-lime-peel helmet won't let me see which database you're using. For PHP, you can use [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), I believe (possibly not, depending on how you handle your date objects).

Comment: @shridhar Run `SELECT NOW()` in your phpmyadmin to know your server timing and compare it with the date time you got in php\

Comment: Why won't you you change your column attribute from `bigint` to `date` and then do it and check?

Comment: guys thank you for your response, i have just edited the question. And as i am not able convert date value properly database side not a problem.

Comment: This `echo date('d-m-y', '1435689000');` and `echo gmdate('d-m-y', '1435689000');` gives same output `30-06-15`. I am not clear in your question. Can you be more specific

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen even i wondered why the server date is showing different for gmdate and date function.

Comment: @shridhar Yeah I wonder too ,Can you say, what is the server date now ?

Comment: 25-05-2015 its displaying correctly

Comment: The functions `date()` and `gmdate()` are used for different purposes, which is why the output is most likely different too. If you want to store dates in a database, why don't you use a more appropriate datatype, such as `DATETIME` or `DATE` in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn the difference between both of these function

1) [**date**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer **timestamp** or the current time if no **timestamp** is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of time().

2) [**gmdate**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

```
string gmdate ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

> **Identical** `to the date() function` **except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)**.

If you've seen the another function it already define that both are identical but [**gmdate**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) returns it in **GMT**

If you echo both of these functions along with `time` you'll understand the difference

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:sP',1435689000);//2015-07-01 00:00:00+05:30

echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:sP',1435689000);//2015-06-30 18:30:00+00:00
```

its because according to the **GMT** timezone your current time is **+0530** ahead of the **GMT**. Thus the output for both are correct but the difference is the **timezones**

Answer (score 0):

We have to set date format before use strtotime function. Because all format which gave by user can not accept by php. We can use like this :

> ```
> $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y" , '03-07-2015');
> echo gmdate('d-m-y', strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
> ```